# Java mail problem with Turkish characters

Tags: java, character-encoding, email, jakarta-mail, turkish

I have problem of showing Turkish characters in mail sent with Java code. The characters are shown as question marks (?) in mail.

```
Message msg = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
msg.setHeader("Content-Encoding","ISO-8859-9");
msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
InternetAddress[] address = {new InternetAddress(to)};
msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, address);
msg.setSubject(subject,"iso-8859-9");
msg.setSentDate(new Date());
msg.setContent(messageText, "text/html;ISO-8859-9");
```

Comment: Quick question. Are you sure the problem is in your code, or perhaps it's your email client that has difficulty displaying this ? Have you reproduced the problem in different clients ?

Comment: Which characters? Can you show an example email?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like ISO-8859-9 should be able to handle your [Turkish letters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turkish_dotted_and_dotless_I) alright. Is it possible that the text is decoded somewhere else with the wrong character encoding? For example, if the body of the email contains text from a web request, another email, or a file, perhaps the wrong decoder is specified at that point.

One way to check would be to print the numeric value of the Unicode code points in the `String`:

```
for (int idx = 0; idx < str.length(); ++idx) {
  System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(str.charAt(idx)));
}
```

If you see `fffd`, that is the "replacement character" and means that the decoding used when the `String` was created could not map a byte (or byte sequence) to a character. If you see `3f`, that is a '?' character, and means that the text was corrupted even farther back.

Answer (score 0):

Use UTF-8, here's a good overview of encoding:
http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Answer (score -1):

You can find the solution here:

http://www.serkankonakci.com/Project/wordpress/2009/02/04/java-mail-ile-mail-gonderme-ornegi/

even with this code, you can send with attachment or single mail in Turkish.
And you can find other Turkish charset problem, just search there.